# decodeAudioData HTML5 Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, buffer, decode, html5-audio

I want to play audio data from an ArrayBuffer... so I generate my array and fill it with microfone input. 
If I draw this data on a canvas it looks like --> 
[image]

So this works!

But if i want to listen to this data with

```
context.decodeAudioData(tmp, function(bufferN) { //tmp is a arrayBuffer
    var out = context.createBufferSource();
    out.buffer = bufferN;
    out.connect(context.destination);
    out.noteOn(0);
}, errorFunction);
```

I dont hear anything... because the errorFunction is called. But error is null!

I also tryed to get the buffer like that:

```
var soundBuffer = context.createBuffer(myArrayBuffer, true/*make mono*/);
```

But i get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified.

anybody who can give me a hint ?

**EDIT 1 (More code and how I get the mic input):**

```
 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {

                liveSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

                // create a ScriptProcessorNode
                if(!context.createScriptProcessor){
                   node = context.createJavaScriptNode(2048, 1, 1);
                } else {
                   node = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
                }


                node.onaudioprocess = function(e){

               var tmp = new Uint8Array(e.inputBuffer.byteLength);
               tmp.set(new      Uint8Array(e.inputBuffer.byteLength), 0);

   //Here comes the code from above.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you also include your code for getting data from the microphone?

Comment: sure. Please look at my changes. Thanks

Comment: i didn't see any fillup of `myArrayBuffer`. looks like it has `undefined` value, so obviously there's nothing to decode.

Comment: sry but i renamed. I dont want to call it "tmp" for stackoverflow. my fold. (Fixed it top)

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953259/using-web-audio-api-decodeaudiodata-with-external-binary-data

Comment: i think helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365335/decodeaudiodata-returning-a-null-error

Comment: When I go to your link I can hear myself talking and it creates a nice feedback loop. Maybe this is specific to your setup? (I'm on Chrome)

Comment: Yes this example in the link is working because i use the direct media object and not my generated buffer. The "not working" code is also in the index.html but as comment. The link shows how it sould look/hear like. (I use chrome too)

Comment: Have you seen this question already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365335/decodeaudiodata-returning-a-null-error, which topic is close to your in the way how an null error is emitted?

Comment: The returned error from the callback function is null because in the current webaudio api spec that function does not return an object error, "callback DecodeErrorCallback = void (); " take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioContext-section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The returned error from the callback function is null because in the current [webaudio api spec](http://w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioContext-section) that function does not return an object error

```
callback DecodeSuccessCallback = void (AudioBuffer decodedData);
callback DecodeErrorCallback = void ();

    void decodeAudioData(ArrayBuffer audioData,
                         DecodeSuccessCallback successCallback,
                         optional DecodeErrorCallback errorCallback);
```

DecodeSuccessCallback is raised when the complete input ArrayBuffer is decoded and stored internally as an AudioBuffer but for some unknown reason decodeAudioData can not decode a live stream.

You can try to play the captured buffer setting the output buffer data when processing audio

```
function connectAudioInToSpeakers(){

  //var context = new webkitAudioContext();  
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {

    var context = new webkitAudioContext();  
    liveSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    // create a ScriptProcessorNode
    if(!context.createScriptProcessor){
       node = context.createJavaScriptNode(2048, 1, 1);
    } else {
       node = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    }


    node.onaudioprocess = function(e){

        try{
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, document.getElementById("myCanvas").width, document.getElementById("myCanvas").height);
            document.getElementById("myCanvas").width = document.getElementById("myCanvas").width;
            ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";

            var input = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            for(var i in input) {
                output[i] = input[i];
                ctx.fillRect(i/4,input[i]*500+200,1,1);
            }


        }catch (e){
            console.log('node.onaudioprocess',e.message);
        }

    }

     // connect the ScriptProcessorNode with the input audio
    liveSource.connect(node);
    // if the ScriptProcessorNode is not connected to an output the "onaudioprocess" event is not triggered in chrome
    node.connect(context.destination);

    //Geb mic eingang auf boxen
    //liveSource.connect(context.destination);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a while I tried to solve this problem again and found a solution:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode

Its not complicated at all, so I created a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/WEM3y/

So activate your mic (tested on chrome v35) and check it out.

The part i have changed:

```
node.onaudioprocess = function(e){

    var outData = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var inData = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

    // Loop through the 4096 samples, copy them to output buffer
    for (var sample = 0; sample < e.outputBuffer.length; sample++) {
      // Set the data in the output buffer for each sample
      outData[sample] = inData[sample]; //Modify your buffer here if you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context initialization might be done as recommended by OJay in [Why does this code work in Safari but not Chrome? Arrrgh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638332/why-does-this-code-work-in-safari-but-not-chrome-arrrgh)